# Getting Problem While Reading Data From Firestore After Converting to custom object

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

In My App I'm trying to read data from Firestore collection and loading it to Recycler View. I am trying to convert looping in querysnapshot documents and then trying to convert document snapshot to Custom Object But I am not getting the proper result. When I try to pass the custom object in List then After Running my app It shows only blank. And BTW, I am setting it with viewpager. One more point -> If instead of Firestore I directly use this line `list.add(object)`then it works fine but It's not working with firebase.

Here is my code.....

```
     val db = Firebase.firestore
        db.collection("/Deal/QuickDeal/homeBanner").orderBy("category").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            for (documents in it.documents) {
                val banner: Banner? = documents.toObject<Banner>(Banner::class.java)
                list.add(banner!!)
            }
        }



        val mAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(list, this)
        binding.banner.adapter = mAdapter
}
}
```

Adapter ->

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(private val images: List<Banner> , private val listener: OnItemClickListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewPagerAdapter.ViewPagerViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewPagerViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),
        View.OnClickListener {
        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        val ivImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image)
        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
            val position = adapterPosition
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                listener.onItemClick(position)
            }
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(position: Int)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewPagerViewHolder {
        return ViewPagerViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.banner_item, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewPagerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(images[position].imageUrl).into(holder.ivImage)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = images.size
}
```

After Running App It doesn't show images and I can't scroll my viewpager and regarding that firestore I'm getting imageUrl and category properly.

Screenshot[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo I added screenshot

Comment: What does `images[position].imageUrl` inside `onBindViewHolder()` return?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm trying to convert imageUrl to imageView.